# Converting an MVC page to a React based page in an already existing React application

Tags: reactjs, tsx, react-tsx

I am using react for the first time and since I've been assigned a task of converting an already existing ASP.NET MVC page to a react page which uses the API's just like before and also is able to fill the dropdown with the API's data provided by the GetClaimTypesData and GetUserToDealerCodesData methods mentioned in my tsx file below.

I am able to load the data in the dropdown's as of now, but, I now need to save the data as the user input to these two dropdown fields and then pass it onto my Start Claim button which is present at the bottom.

I have not yet been able to save the data into an object so that I can then pass that object to the Start Claim button onClick event.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GetClaimTypes } from "../../aPIHandler/claimApiHandler";
import { GetUserToDealerCodes } from "../../aPIHandler/claimApiHandler";
import { Claim } from "../../types/claim";
import { ClaimTypes } from "../../types/claimTypes";
import { UserToDealerCodes } from "../../types/userToDealerCodes";
import { DataItemsWithCount } from "../../types/dataItemsWithCount";
import { DataItems } from "../../types/dataItems";
import { useAppDispatch } from "../../reduxStore/hooks";
import { changeHeaderText, changePageTitle, changePageDetailDescription } from "../../reduxStore/pageDetailsSlice";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { MockData } from "../../config/host";
//import { GetStatusIcon, GetStatusCssClass } from "../../util";

const pageSize: number = 10;
const pageNo: number = 1;

const StartClaim = () =\> {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    //const ClaimRespond = (claimId: string) => navigate('/claim/' + claimId + '/respond');
    const GoBack = () => navigate(-1);
    
    
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    dispatch(changePageTitle("Start Claim"));
    dispatch(changeHeaderText("Claims"));
    dispatch(changePageDetailDescription("You can view all your claims on this portal. To make a claim select the \"New Claim\" link below."));
    
    const [searchRegistration, setSearchRegistration] = useState("");
    const [claimTypes, setClaimTypes] = useState<DataItems<ClaimTypes>>();
    const [userToDealerCodes, setUserToDealerCodes] = useState<DataItems<UserToDealerCodes>>();
    //const mockClaimTypes = MockData.ClaimTypes;
    //const mockUserToDealerCodes = MockData.UserDealerCodes;
    const GetClaimTypesData = async () => {
        
        const prommise = await GetClaimTypes();
        if (prommise?.data != null) {
            setClaimTypes(prommise);
        }
        else if (prommise.error > 0) {
            //Todo: Error handler
        }
    };
    const GetUserToDealerCodesData = async () => {
    
        const promise = await GetUserToDealerCodes();
        if (promise?.data != null) {
            setUserToDealerCodes(promise);
        }
        else if (promise.error > 0) {
            //Todo: Error handler
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        GetClaimTypesData();
        GetUserToDealerCodesData();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
    
                <div className="row claim-search">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <a className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={() => GoBack}><i className="fas fa-arrow-left btn-icon"></i><span>Back</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
                        <span className="claim-section-text">Start Claim</span>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                                <label className="control-label" htmlFor="registration"><span>Registration</span><sup title="Required">*</sup></label>
                                {/*<input className="form-control input-sm" id="registration" name="registration" value="@claim.ClaimRegistration" data-bind="value : claimRegistration" type="text" aria-required="true" title="This field is required."/>*/}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                                <label className="control-label" htmlFor="claimtype"><span>Claim Type</span><sup title="Required">*</sup></label>
                                <br />
                                <select className="form-control dropdown-claims input-xl">
                                    {claimTypes?.data.map((x: any) => (
                                        <option key={x.claimTypeId} value={x.claimTypeId}>
                                            {x.title}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                                <label className="control-label" htmlFor="userdealercode"><span>User Dealer Code</span><sup title="Required">*</sup></label>
                                <br />
                                <select className="form-control dropdown-claims input-xl">
                                    {userToDealerCodes?.data.map((x: any) => (
                                        <option key={x.userToDealerCodeId} value={x.cuserToDealerCodeIdlaimTypeId}>
                                            {x.dealerCode}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 mt-4">
                        <div className="claim-error-message">
                            <span id="ErrorMessage"><i className="fal fa-frown btn-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i><span className="claim-error-separator">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span><span id="ErrorMessageText"></span></span>&nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
                        <div className="pull-right">
                            <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={() => GoBack}>Cancel</button>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" id="submitClaim" data-bind="click : ValidateClaimCreate">Start Claim</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

};

export default StartClaim;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `onchange` prop to the `select` element, and then add a function which collects the data of the selected option on the change.

Before that, you will need to add some state values, to collect the data from your onchange function.

```
const [selectedClaimType, setSelectedClaimType] = useState<ClaimType>();
const [selectedUserToDealerCode, setSelectedUserToDealerCode] = useState<UserToDealerCode>();
```

onChange prop function `handleChange`:

```
<div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                                <label className="control-label" htmlFor="claimtype"><span>Claim Type</span><sup title="Required">*</sup></label>
                                <br />
                                <select className="form-control dropdown-claims input-xl" onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "claimType")>
                                    {claimTypes?.data.map((x: any) => (
                                        <option key={x.claimTypeId} value={x.claimTypeId}>
                                            {x.title}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                                <label className="control-label" htmlFor="userdealercode"><span>User Dealer Code</span><sup title="Required">*</sup></label>
                                <br />
                                <select className="form-control dropdown-claims input-xl" onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "userToDealerCode")>
                                    {userToDealerCodes?.data.map((x: any) => (
                                        <option key={x.userToDealerCodeId} value={x.cuserToDealerCodeIdlaimTypeId}>
                                            {x.dealerCode}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

The `handleChange` can look something like this:

```
const handleChange = (event, type) => {
   if (type === "claimType) {
      setSelectedClaimType(event.target.value)
   }
   if (type === "userToDealerCode"){
      setSelectedUserToDealerCode(event.target.value)
   }
}
```

Then you can add a `onClick` function to you `Start Claim` button. Your `onClick` function can then use the information stored in the two new state values

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" id="submitClaim" data-bind="click : ValidateClaimCreate" onClick={startClaim}>Start Claim</button>

const startClaim = () => { 
.......
submitClaim(selectedClaimType, selectedUserToDealerCode);
}
```